# Trailer Hitch Limits on 2007 PT Cruiser

Tags: towing, weight

I'm planning on moving and driving my 2007 PT cruiser from the Phoenix, AZ to Chicago, IL regions - A trip that is roughly 1700 miles, I believe.

I will be loading up most of my belongings into the PT cruiser, but believe I may need to get an additional trailor for the rest of the things I need to take with me.

However, I've been looking through the owners manual and trying to find information online and I'm confused about what the highest gross trailer weight my vehicle will be able to tow will be, along with what size trailer hitch would be the most appropriate for the vehicle.

I drive a 2007 Chrysler PT Cruiser, 2.4L base model.

I don't currently have a trailer hitch, but am trying to find the most appropriate one to purchase and have installed for the vehicle so that I can get a (uhaul?) trailer attached for the move.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing your towing capacity for the [PT to be ~2200lbs](http://www.uktow.com/towing%20capacity.asp?make=Chrysler&model1=PT%20Cruiser). Please remember, this towing capacity also includes any weight which is on the inside of the vehicle, such as people and cargo. If you are moving an entire household, you'll most likely exceed this by quite a bit. Most of the hitches I'm seeing available for the PT are only rated at 2000lbs, so you'll need to take this into account as well.

Comment: I'm not so much moving an entire household; I live alone. I'm throwing away most of my larger furniture, but will end up carrying on the trailor a queen sized (Casper) mattress and metal platform bedframe that came with it, along with possibly a bike, mini-fridge, and some boxes. Inside the vehicle I'll have clothes, two 50" TV's, A computer monitor, a bag with my three laptops, and other boxes containing various household things (Like power strips and things that plug into them). I think it's a 50/50 chance I hit max load using U-Hauls 5x9' trailer w/ Ramp with empty weight of 1240lbs. Thanks

Comment: The biggest issue is not with the ability to tow the weight, but with the ability to stop the weight once it's moving. Braking ability should be accounted for as well as the ability to tow.